# Is it possible to make an object which represents degrees in c#?

Tags: c#, degrees

Is it possible to have a class or struct which contains a `float` value which can only be between 0 and 359.999... where if you increment it past its max value it resets to 0 or a positive value below 360 when decrementing past 0.

When implemented, it would look something like this:

```
Degrees angle = 359;
angle += 2;
Console.WriteLine(angle);
```

Output:

```
1
```

Or when decrementing below 0:

```
Degrees angle = 0;
angle -= 2;
Console.WriteLine(angle);
```

Output:

```
358
```

It would also need to be able to increment/decrement values above 360f so adding 361.5 to 0 would output 1.5

Comment: You want to create a new class and implement [Operator Overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading)

Comment: A `struct` would likely be the best way to represent it, but yes it is possible.

Comment: http://james-ramsden.com/angle-class-for-c/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a combination of [operator overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading) and [implicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) keywords, it's pretty easy to do:

```
public readonly struct Degrees
{
    private readonly float _value;

    public Degrees(float value)
    {
        _value = value < 0
            ? 360 - (Math.Abs(value) % 360)
            : value % 360;
    }

    public override string ToString() 
        => _value.ToString();

    public static implicit operator Degrees(float f) 
        => new Degrees(f);

    public static Degrees operator +(Degrees a, Degrees b) 
        => new Degrees(a._value + b._value);
    public static Degrees operator -(Degrees a, Degrees b) 
        => new Degrees(a._value - b._value);
}
```

Now you can write this:

```
Degrees angle = 359f;
angle += 2f;
Console.WriteLine(angle);
```

Which will output:

```
1
```

Or this:

```
Degrees angle = 0;
angle -= 2;
Console.WriteLine(angle);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create strct like

```
public struct Degrees
{
   private decimal _angle;

   public decimal angle
   {
       get { return _angle; }
       set { _angle = value % 360; }
   }
}
```

And then use it as

```
Degrees degrees = new Degrees();
degrees.angle = 361.5m + 0m;
```